# Given a set of rectangles, do any overlap?

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of rectangles represented as tuples `(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` where `xmin` and `xmax` are the left and right edges, and `ymin` and `ymax` are the bottom and top edges, respectively - is there any pair of overlapping rectangles in the set?

A straightforward approach is to compare every pair of rectangles for overlap, but this is `O(n^2)` - it should be possible to do better.

Update: `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` are *integers*.  So a condition for rectangle 1 and rectangle 2 to overlap is `xmin_2 <= xmax_1 AND xmax_2 >= xmin_1`; similarly for the Y coordinates.

If one rectangle contains another, the pair is considered overlapping.

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: The question is "is there any pair of overlapping rectangles in the set".

Comment: Can the list be sorted?

Comment: Your question is very generic and you can find many articles with a simple search that discuss the issue.

Comment: Try to sort the rectangles first.

Comment: @Evorlor sure; the list is not in any particular input order but the algorithm is free to sort it in any way desired.

Comment: Should the result be a boolean?  A pair of intersecting rectangles?  All pairs of intersecting rectangles?

Comment: I don't understand why you guys don't get the question.  It seems pretty straight forward to me.  It is an algorithmic question, not a coding question.

Comment: @Degustaf A boolean is all that is needed - are there any pairs overlapping, or not?  No need to identify which pair.

Comment: is a containing rectangle considered overlapping?

Comment: @Alex Yes; I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in O(N log N) approach the following way.

Firstly, "squeeze" your y coordinates. That is, sort all y coordinates (tops and bottoms) together in one array, and then replace coordinates in your rectangle description by its index in a sorted array. Now you have all y's being integers from 0 to 2n-1, and the answer to your problem did not change (in case you have equal y's, see below).

Now you can divide the plane into 2n-1 stripes, each unit height, and each rectangle spans completely several of them. Prepare an segment tree for these stripes. (See [this link](http://se7so.blogspot.ru/2012/12/segment-trees-and-lazy-propagation.html) for segment tree overview.)

Then, sort all x-coordinates in question (both left and right boundaries) in the same array, keeping for each coordinate the information from which rectangle it comes and whether this is a left or right boundary.

Then go through this list, and as you go, maintain list of all the rectangles that are currently "active", that is, for which you have seen a left boundary but not right boundary yet.

More exactly, in your segment tree you need to keep for each stripe how many active rectangles cover it. When you encounter a left boundary, you need to add 1 for all stripes between a corresponding rectangle's bottom and top. When you encounter a right boundary, you need to subtract one. Both addition and subtraction can be done in O(log N) using the mass update (lazy propagation) of the segment tree.

And to actually check what you need, when you meet a left boundary, before adding 1, check, whether there is at least one stripe between bottom and top that has non-zero coverage. This can be done in O(log N) by performing a sum on interval query in segment tree. If the sum on this interval is greater than 0, then you have an intersection.

```
 squeeze y's
 sort all x's
 t = segment tree on 2n-1 cells
 for all x's
     r = rectangle for which this x is
     if this is left boundary
         if t.sum(r.bottom, r.top-1)>0   // O(log N) request
              you have occurence
         t.add(r.bottom, r.top-1, 1)  // O(log N) request
     else
         t.subtract(r.bottom, r.top-1)  // O(log N) request
```

You should implement it carefully taking into account whether you consider a touch to be an intersection or not, and this will affect your treatment of equal numbers. If you consider touch an intersection, then all you need to do is, when sorting y's, make sure that of all points with equal coordinates all tops go after all bottoms, and similarly when you sort x's, make sure that of all equal x's all lefts go before all rights.

Comment: You need to check more than just whether the set already contains a value between the top and bottom: it might be that the rectangle whose left edge you are currently considering intersects an "active" rectangle that both begins above and ends below it.

Comment: That is O(n^2) if you only go from left to right. Consider the trivial case where all rectangles have the same left edge, but different heights.

Comment: @Petr good point about the "touches".  I edited the question to specify that the inputs are integers and to clarify what is considered an overlap.

Comment: @Tibos Good point; I'm definitely interested in performance for edge cases like that.

Comment: @Tibos, no, it was not, because in a set (`std::set` or similar bst) you can check whether there is an element between two given values in O(log N) time. Anyway, I have corrected that answer because the previous was wrong. The new one is O(N log N) still, though much more difficult to implement.

Comment: But 'squeezing' and sorting the lists also take time.

Comment: @BrentWashburne, yes, but it can easily be done within O(N log N)

Comment: Looks good now! +2 :)  My only quibble would be that the Wikipedia page for interval trees doesn't really go into any detail about O(log n) range updates.  If you could provide a good link, that would be great.  I also looked into Fenwick trees, which can be used with a very clever trick to enable O(log n) range updates: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33014/range-update-range-query-with-binary-indexed-trees

Comment: @j_random_hacker, it seems that I was somewhat wrong and that segment tree is a more correct name for this data structure. Wikipedia has rather strange pages for both segment and interval tree describing not what I want, but for segment trees many proper links pop up in google. Among them http://se7so.blogspot.ru/2012/12/segment-trees-and-lazy-propagation.html that mentions lazy propagation as well. And yes, Fenwick tree can also be used here.

Comment: @Petr Instead of just finding out if there are any overlapping rectangles or not, if we want to find out which rectangles overlap, what changes are needed in the algorithm? Is it possible to do this in O(N log N)?

Comment: Would be nice if you could illustrate a small example

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try a plane sweep algorithm? Plane sweep is a design paradigm widely used in computational geometry, so it has the advantage that it is well studied and a lot of documetation is available online. Take a look at [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/). The line segment intersection problem should give you some ideas, also the area of union of rectangles.

Read about [Bentley-Ottman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) algorithm for line segment intersection, the problem is very similar to yours and it has O((n+k)logn) where k is the number of intersections, nevertheless, since your rectangles sides are parallel to the x and y axis, it is way more simpler so you can modify Bentley-Ottman to run in O(nlogn +k) since you won't need to update the event heap, since all intersections can be detected once the rectangle is visited and won't modify the sweep line ordering, so no need to mantain the events. To retrieve all intersecting rectangles with the new rectangle I suggest using a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) on the ymin and ymax for each rectangle, it will give you all points lying in the interval defined by the ymin and ymax of the new rectangle and thus the rectangles intersecting it.

If you need more details you should take a look at chapter two of M. de Berg, et. al [Computational Geometry book](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/). Also take a look at [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.3275&rep=rep1&type=pdf), they show how to find all intersections between convex polygons in O(nlogn + k), it might prove simpler than my above suggestion since all data strcutures are explained there and your rectangles are convex, a very good thing in this case.

Comment: I was thinking of returning all intersections, but hen I realized it was to decide just if there is at least one intersection or not. In that case it should be enough once you find the first intersection, so ignore the k on my answer. Also, it could be faster doing n queries in a [2d range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), and stop once you find one. Complexity will be O(nlog^2n), but with fractional cascading would be reduced to O(nlogn). An [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) might prove useful too.

Comment: If you know offhand whether that O(nlog n + k) algorithm for finding all intersections between convex polygons can be "restricted" to an O(nlog n) algorithm for finding a single intersection, it would be great to mention that.  (It probably can, but this doesn't follow automatically...  And I'm too lazy to read the paper myself :-P)

Comment: Well it is the same procedure as finding all, but when you find the first one you stop the algorithm and return true. If you end the process without finding any one you return false. In both cases you will need ordering the x coordinates and do at most n queries to an interval tree, so you can't avoid that O(nlogn) complexity and the k comes from the number of intersections found, so k is at most 1.

Comment: From your last comment it sounds like this algorithm will indeed find 1 intersection in time O(nlog n) -- my point was that AFAICT, absent information on the particular algorithm, the fact that it is O(nlog n + k) to find *all* k intersections doesn't imply that 1 can be found in O(nlog n).  It does imply that a "No" answer can be returned in O(nlog n) time, but if there are k > 0 then it seems to me that it's still possible that an O(nlog n + k) algorithm somehow pays ω(1) cost just to find any of them: this cost could be amortised across the k-1 later intersections.

Comment: The algorithm consists of 2 main steps, the first sorts the rectangle x coordinates, and then process each rectangle in that order. When you first see a rectangle you add it to a binary tree in O(logn) time, and by adding it you can detect if such rectangle intersects any other previously seen rectangle. You can report each intersecting rectangle in O(k'), or just count the number in O(1). When you see the end of a rectangle you remove it for the tree in O(logn). So if you don't report the intersections the total cost of the second main step is O(nlogn) plus O(nlogn) for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

You can do better by building a new list of rectangles that do not overlap.  From the set of rectangles, take the first one and add it to the list.  It obviously does not overlap with any others because it is the only one in the list.  Take the next one from the set and see if it overlaps with the first one in the list.  If it does, return true; otherwise, add it to the list.  Repeat for all rectangles in the set.

Each time, you are comparing rectangle `r` with the `r-1` rectangles in the list.  This can be done in `O(n*(n-1)/2)` or `O((n^2-n)/2)`.  You can even apply this algorithm to the original set without having to create a new list.

Comment: This is still O(N^2), and in fact not faster than straightforward checking of all n*(n-1)/2 pairs (with immediate stopping if you find the intersection)